Are old cardano node versions invalidated
Just checked one server which is running old node version Cardano Node 8.9.0 and i can see it has stuck and stopped syncing at 1st september. Are any old node versions invalidated now?
bam@nsserver:~$ cardano-cli query tip --mainnet
{
    "block": 10781330,
    "epoch": 506,
    "era": "Babbage",
    "hash": "e757d57eb8dc9500a61c60a39fadb63d9be6973ba96ae337fd24453d4d15c343",
    "slot": 133660799,
    "slotInEpoch": 431999,
    "slotsToEpochEnd": 1,
    "syncProgress": "99.80"


You need 9.1.1 to cross the hard fork.

To add extra context to Sam's answer, the old version of node will not be able to follow the Chang HF which happened on Sep 2nd.

That what i understoood from logs, and already updated. Just wondering why id havent seen anywhere that ALL old node versions will be invalid as this hard fork. If i understand it right it wasnt the case with previous versions right?

I remember seeing it.
